# DocuSign template recipient roles using API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create an envelope with composite templates using DocuSign SOAP based API call in my .net web application.
First, I have created a template and recipient roles for the template in my DocuSign account.
I can download the template and view the XML from the DocuSign UI.

Before I go ahead an create an envelope from the template, I need to assign recipients to specific roles
at run time. In order to do so, I need to retrieve role information from the template at run time.
I am looking into the SOAP/REST API guide for an API call that will allow me to retrieve role information and I checked the following API calls..

REST

- Get Template

SOAP

- RequestTemplate
- RequestTemplateWithDocumentFields

They do not return recipient role information. Is there an API call that will allow me to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST Get Template will work for what you're looking for. The information will come back as `roleName` under the appropriate node in `recipients` (ex. `signer`)

### Get Template

This retrieves the definition of the specified template.

```
URL: /accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}
```

Formats: *XML*, *JSON*

HTTP Method: *GET*

Parameters: *The only required parameter is the template ID.*

### Example Request Body

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}
X-DocuSign-Authentication:<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><Integrato
rKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

---

Information directly taken from the [DocuSign REST API Guide, version 2](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=202)